# What is the Profile build target used for in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt-creator

In Qt Creator, in addition to the Debug and Release targets, there is also a Profile build target. I'm familiar with Debug and Release, but what is Profile used for? I couldn't find any documentation about it.

[image]